# Creating derivative work based on a project under apache license - Dealing with original notices in source codes

Tags: licensing, apache-license

There is a library licensed under Apache License 2.0 that I extended its functionality in multiple new Classes. Also some of the original Classes of the project had to be modified in which some of them slightly changed but some modified a lot. Multiple new methods was added and some older methods changed and some moved and etc. Now I think the library is more useful than before.

I know in Apache License one can create a Derivate work from an original source or object.

Subject to the part 4 of the license (4. Redistribution), I created prominent notices in modified files that I modified or added these parts.

Also I'm going to bring the original Notice files and also any materials are needed to show my respect and thanks to the original work.

Now my problem is in the modified files. Above each file, there is a notice like this in the form of comments:

```
Licensed to the SOME_NAME under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The SOME_NAME licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 ...
```

I don't know how to deal with those notices. For example in the case of notice files, I can put

```
Copyright [yyyy] My Identity
```

in the original Notice.

But in the source files, should I keep that notices about

```
Licensed to the SOME_NAME
```

above the modified source codes even though I've modified them?

Also I don't know its worth mentioning or not that I'm going to keep the license to be as Apache in my work.

Thank you for your interest in subject and helping me.

Comment: The simplest solution is to leave all the existing notices alone.  If you want to add extra comments on what you have done, make them an addition to what's already there.  If you have modified files, then they are derivative works, so the original copyright holders still have rights over the new files.

Comment: Thank you @SimonB. Yes your right. Its the simplest. So you think adding additional notice that these modifications belong to me is sufficient and is not that leaving "Licensed to the SOME_NAME" part means that my modifications still belong to the original licensor?

Comment: The better question is obviously I don't have rights over the the whole project, but really they have rights over the new files in derivative works in apache license?

Comment: Brand new files are yours, and you can licence them how you like.  If a file is modified, then whoever had rights over it still has rights - all the parts of it that they created are still theirs.

Comment: Is SOME_NAME is actually some real name? Can you put here the exact/full copy of the licence text? If this code is licence only to a person X - than technically a person Y doesn't have permission to use and modify the code at all - let alone licence it to others. So please clarify this.

Comment: Thank you @Dipan for commenting, SimonB 's comments were really helpful and I upvoted both. Yes it is. Its actually licensed to Apache Commons! Do you think it makes any differences when it is licensed to a Person? I have not noticed such a thing in Apache License. Unfortunately sometimes ago, in the process of changing this damn GIT I lost the whole works! and I could not bring it back :( now I only have the object form for my personal use... (Thank god I was not that idiot to not to copy the compileds from git) So I don't have it right now to paste the exact license for you